# Is there a way to make multiple rectangles that isn't connected (have multiple locations throughout the frame)out of only 1 frame rectangle?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to create 2 JPanels out of one JPanel Object, for example in order to create 2 panels is to manually like
JPanel panel = new JPanel(); and JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
And if I'm creating multiple JPanel objects, this will make my code messy, is there a way to use some sort of way to use only 1 JPanel object that would look something like this?

[image]

The black rectangles representing the JPanels.

Comment: Images should be posted in this forum so we can see the image as part of your question. Not sure I understand the question. This is always the way a UI is designed. You add multiple components to a panel.  Why is adding multiple JPanels different that adding multiple labels or text fields. The anwer is to use the appropriate layout manager. See the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Or another option is to paint the rectangle onto a single panel. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a couple of working examples.

Comment: @camickr So, I used the image as an example of the 2 rectangles to show that I want to completely different x and y-axis with different horizontal and width parameters using the same JPanel object

Comment: 1) you still haven't posted the image in the forum 2) I suggested you use custom painting if you want random placement of the rectangles.